# Issue while writing to Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

We have a Spark job which reads the data from GCS and load it into BigTable. This job is working fine in lower environment but we are getting weird issue in production environment. We are using the HBase bulk put api to store the data into Bigtable. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Logs

```
2021-04-07T13:18:14Z    ERROR   {"class":"org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler","message":"Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message."}
2021-04-07T13:18:14Z    ERROR   {"class":"org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler","message":"Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message."}
2021-04-07T13:18:14.118721886Z  DEFAULT Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 175 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 175.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 1445, gcp-prd-gcs-bigtable-loader-a32x7upkbwpxe-w-27, executor 36): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 125 actions: StatusRuntimeException: 125 times, servers with issues: bigtable.googleapis.com at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.getExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:187)  at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.handleExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:141)   at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.mutate(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:132) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext$$anonfun$bulkPut$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(HBaseContext.scala:230)    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext$$anonfun$bulkPut$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(HBaseContext.scala:230)    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext$$anonfun$bulkPut$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HBaseContext.scala:230) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext$$anonfun$bulkPut$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HBaseContext.scala:228) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext.org$apache$hadoop$hbase$spark$HBaseContext$$hbaseForeachPartition(HBaseContext.scala:489) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext$$anonfun$bulkPut$1.apply(HBaseContext.scala:225)  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext$$anonfun$bulkPut$1.apply(HBaseContext.scala:225)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.119097387Z  DEFAULT 
2021-04-07T13:18:14.119418925Z  DEFAULT Driver stacktrace:
2021-04-07T13:18:14.119736812Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1926)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.120068638Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1914)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.130625639Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1913)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.131131757Z  DEFAULT     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.131569273Z  DEFAULT     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.131950286Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1913)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.132402917Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.132735888Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.133129775Z  DEFAULT     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.13354306Z   DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:948)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.133872192Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2147)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.134181766Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2096)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.134503241Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2085)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.134901523Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.135328164Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:759)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.135739829Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.136105777Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.136498026Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.136840822Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.144167827Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:980)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.144680824Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:978)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.155168463Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.155558017Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.155867426Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.156168331Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:978)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.156605051Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext.bulkPut(HBaseContext.scala:224)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.160636853Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.JavaHBaseContext.bulkPut(JavaHBaseContext.scala:166)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.161087983Z  DEFAULT     at com.gcp.gcstobigtable.ReadWTxnP2FromGcsAndWriteToBigTable.doBulkPut(ReadWTxnP2FromGcsAndWriteToBigTable.java:154)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.161516459Z  DEFAULT     at com.gcp.gcstobigtable.ReadWTxnP2FromGcsAndWriteToBigTable.main(ReadWTxnP2FromGcsAndWriteToBigTable.java:62)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.161971898Z  DEFAULT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.162391968Z  DEFAULT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.162795326Z  DEFAULT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.16313107Z   DEFAULT     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.191936436Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.192445084Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.192877426Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.193322881Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.193720635Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.194132375Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.194645147Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.195099816Z  DEFAULT     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.432439159Z  DEFAULT Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:655)    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:274)   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105) at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.434223483Z  DEFAULT Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:655)    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:274)   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105) at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.436006312Z  DEFAULT Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:655)    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:274)   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105) at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.440979599Z  DEFAULT Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:655)    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:274)   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105) at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.44272817Z   DEFAULT Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:655)    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:274)   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105) at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-07T13:18:14.448014227Z  DEFAULT Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:160)  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:655)    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:274)   at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105) at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code:

```
Configuration conf = BigtableConfiguration.configure(projectId,bigTableInstanceId);
JavaHBaseContext hbaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(sc, conf);
hbaseContext.bulkPut(bqDataRdd, bigTableName, bulkPutObject);
```

Comment: Hi, is this still an issue for you? if not, how did you manage to make it work?

Comment: The issue was with the load, our one load is of around 4-5M. Hence job was giving this issue. To avoid this problem, we are iterating all the parquet file in the specified folder and loading them one by one instead of loading all the 40-50 parquet files together which has around 4-5M of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the load, our one load is of around 4-5M. Hence job was giving this issue. To avoid this problem, we are iterating all the parquet file in the specified folder and loading them one by one instead of loading all the 40-50 parquet files together which has around 4-5M of data